# Convergent and divergent series with root test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Find a convergent series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ with positive entries, such that $\lim_{x\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}=1$

Find a divergent series with similar properties.

Any hints on that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You say: "... such that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}$" - What do you mean?

Comment: It should be $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ instead of $\lim_{x\to\infty}$.

Comment: My bad! I mean the limit equal to 1

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Think to the Riemann series $\sum_{n\ge1}\frac1{n^\alpha}$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$. It is convergent.

Let  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty1$. It is divergent.

Is it okay?

**ADD:**

$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{n^2}=e^{\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{2\ln n}{n}}=e^{\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{2}{n}}=e^0=1.$

Answer (score 0):

Take $a_n=\dfrac{1}{n}$, $b_n=\dfrac{1}{n^2}$.

Then $\sqrt[n]{a_n}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n}}\to 1,$
$\sqrt[n]{b_n}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n^2}}\to 1$,
while
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}<\infty.$$

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}=\infty.$$

Comment: So if the sum is less than infinity then it diverges?

Comment: This sum of positive terms diverges if and only if it is equal to infinity.